# PHP Change 24 hour datetime using strtotime

Tags: php, datetime

I am using `strtotime` for saving date like `strtotime($_POST['end_date'])` and this give me format `1441785600` that show very fine in google calendar but when I save string like

```
Thu Sep 03 2015 14:00:00 (24 hour format)
```

Data stop displaying in google calendar, I want to convert above sample `(24Hours)` using `strtotime` and convert it into something like that `1441785600`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, `1441785600` is not 12 hour format or 24 hour format, it's a unix timestamp, and can be displayed in both 12- and 24 hour format.- So why not just send that to google?

Comment: Well, you might want to use the ```date()``` function?

Comment: Is `strtotime('Thu Sep 03 2015 14:00:00');` not working? I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: strtotime is not a format its UNIX timestamp whom you can convert in any desired format using php date() function just need to pass your format.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this which currently doesn't give as you want, but may be useful-

```
$date = 'Sep 03 2015 14:00:00';
$parsedDate = date_parse_from_format('M d Y H:i:s', $date);
$time_stamp = mktime(
$parsedDate['hour'], $parsedDate['minute'], $parsedDate['second'],
  date('n', strtotime($parsedDate['month'])), $parsedDate['day'], $parsedDate['year'],
  date('I')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$dateString = 'Thu Sep 03 2015 14:00:00 (24 hour format)';
echo strtotime(preg_replace('~\w+\s(.+)\s\(.+~','\1',trim($dateString)));
```